# popping to UIViewController causing crash - message sent to deallocated instance

Tags: objective-c, ipad

I have a `UIViewController` I am showing as a Modal popover.  When that view is done being used I am popping to a particular location in my `UINavigationBar`:

```
[[appDelegate.homeViewController navigationController] popToViewController:[[appDelegate.homeViewController navigationController ].viewControllers objectAtIndex:2] animated:YES];
```

The View Controller presenting the modal `UIViewController` is mentioned in the crash below:

```
*** -[ClientDetailsViewController respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x8c17650
```

How can I track this down and see what is causing my crash?

Comment: well if `homeViewController` is your `ClientDetailsViewController` then you need to figure out why that is being deallocated.  Is it being held onto as a `strong/retain` reference in the app delegate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I track this down and see what is causing my crash?

Simply activate **Zombies**.

- In Xcode4, hold the <kbd>alt</kbd> key while choosing "**Product**" > "**Run**" from the menu to show the Schemes dialog (or choose Edit Schemes to show it).
- Then in the "**Diagnostics**" tab, check the "**Enable Zombie Objects**" checkbox

[image: Diagnostics Dialog]
Now when an object is used after it has been deallocated, you will be able to see which object is concerned and when it has been over-released.

---

Moreover, don't hesitate to **use the static analyzer** from the "**Product**" -> "**Analyze**" menu so that Xcode will tell you every memory management errors (and others) he can find in your code.

[image: Static Analyzer example]

You should always run this "Analyze" tool once in a while and fix ALL the warnings it displays, as it is a very good tool to tell you what may be wrong in your code and is of very good advice.

Not having any warning when you run this tool is not a guarantee that your code won't crash, but having warnings when you run this tool quite guarantee you the're something to be fixed in your code.

Comment: I actually ran profiler using the Zombies options.  Turns out I had a UIWebView delegate method that was being called automatically on the UIViewController being popped off the stack - thanks

Comment: Yes, never forget to reset your `UIWebView`'s `delegate` to nil before the delegate object is deallocated, as explained [here in the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIWebView/delegate) ;)